# Recursion Tree - recurrence problem

Tags: algorithms

I have to solve the recurrence using recursion tree method.

[Image of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsa9X.png)

The normal problem is that there is a number in front of T, so we can see how many lines(edge) to divide, but I don't know how to solve this problem because the number in front of T is 1.

Plus, I don't know why the problem is divide into two when n is equal to 1 and n is greater than 1.
Thanks